# Negative Lookbehind to exclude word of certain length in java

Tags: java, regex, negative-lookbehind

I have a regex as

```
\p{L}+[\s,،]*(خیابان)?[\s,،]*\p{L}+[\s,،]*(کوچه|کوی)?[\s,،]*\p{L}+[\s,،]*(پلاک \s*\d+)?(\s*کد پستی \s*\d{9})?
```

This Regex matches any Latin char with length 3 or more. Like 
ABC, ABCDE greater than 3  are matched.

All I wanted is, this regex to match only in case the latin char is greater than 6(let's say). I don't want to change this above regex but only want to exclude latin char matches smaller than 6.

So I added Negetive Lookbehind as

```
(?<!\w{1,6})
```

Now the regex becomes

```
\p{L}+[\s,،]*(خیابان)?[\s,،]*\p{L}+[\s,،]*(کوچه|کوی)?[\s,،]*\p{L}+[\s,،]*(پلاک \s*\d+)?(\s*کد پستی \s*\d{9})?(?<!\w{1,6})
```

But here all the length latin char are excluded.

How can I add negative lookbehind to exclude latin char within length {1 to 6}?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex failed because negative lookbehind only check 1-6 word from the end of your string.

For example, with string "A**BCDEFG**" has 7 character, and your negative lookbehind see that "**BCDEFG**" is 6 character, then exclude all your string.

I think you should fix the negative lookbehind like this:

```
(?<!^\w{1,6})
```

Pay attention the "^", it means your lookbehind has to check from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by 2.
2 x 3 = 6

`(?:\p{L}+[\s,\u060C]*(\u062E\u06CC\u0627\u0628\u0627\u0646)?[\s,\u060C]*\p{L}+[\s,\u060C]*(\u06A9\u0648\u0686\u0647|\u06A9\u0648\u06CC)?[\s,\u060C]*\p{L}+[\s,\u060C]*(\u067E\u0644\u0627\u06A9[ ]\s*\d+)?(\s*\u06A9\u062F[ ]\u067E\u0633\u062A\u06CC[ ]\s*\d{9})?){2}`

Expanded

```
 (?:
      \p{L}+ [\s,\u060C]* 
      (                                              # (1 start)
           \u062E \u06CC \u0627 \u0628 \u0627 \u0646 
      )?                                             # (1 end)
      [\s,\u060C]* \p{L}+ [\s,\u060C]* 
      (                                              # (2 start)
           \u06A9 \u0648 \u0686 \u0647 
        |  \u06A9 \u0648 \u06CC 
      )?                                             # (2 end)
      [\s,\u060C]* \p{L}+ [\s,\u060C]* 
      (                                              # (3 start)
           \u067E \u0644 \u0627 \u06A9 [ ] \s* \d+ 
      )?                                             # (3 end)
      (                                              # (4 start)
           \s* \u06A9 \u062F 
           [ ] \u067E \u0633 \u062A \u06CC 
           [ ] \s* \d{9} 
      )?                                             # (4 end)
 ){2}
```

Comment: @sin What if I want to have more than 9 letters to match? I changed to  3*3 as {3} at the end but now single خیابان doesn't match.

Comment: @LaxmiKadariya - Because there is only 6 in  `خیابان` . https://regex101.com/r/jM3wvt/1 What you want is `{?: ...){2,3}` eg. 6-9

Answer (score 0):

You should use a positive lookahead which will check that all latin chars should be greater than 6. This will help you:

```
(?=\w{6,})\p{L}+[\s,،]*(خیابان)?[\s,،]*\p{L}+[\s,،]*(کوچه|کوی)?[\s,،]*\p{L}+[\s,،]*(پلاک \s*\d+)?(\s*کد پستی \s*\d{9})?
```